# How to bind a param inside of single quotes in PHP PDO for QCMDEXC

Tags: php, pdo, db2

In order to call a program on the IBMI, I need to use the QCMDEXC to call the program.  An example of what i'm trying to do is

```
$query = "CALL QCMDEXC('CALL PGM(IBMIPGM) PARM(?,?)')";
```

These params are in and out variables from the program.  How do i bind a pdo param using:

```
$result->bindParam(1, $invalue, PDO::PARAM_STR|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, 11);
$result->bindParam(2, $outvalue, PDO::PARAM_STR|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, 11);
```

I realized that the single quotes inside the statement are causing the havoc, but in order for the statement to work, it needs to be structured as such, unless there is a workaround I don't know of.

Comment: I spent a while looking to try to help you with this, digging through IMB's documentation, but I couldn't find anything. I'm assuming this just doesn't work, right? Is it failing on the PHP side or the IBM side? Also, if you do figure this, please post an answer because I bet there will be a handful of people pulling their hair out and you'll be a life-saver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK so much to cover here.
First, the QSYS2.QCMDEXC procedure only accepts one parameter, that parameter is the string of the command to run, up to 32k length.
Second, it does not return anything, not even a status (but will throw an sql error if it fails).
But there is a QSYS2.QCMDEXC Scalar function, which will return an integer of 1 for success or -1 for fail. Which one you use is up to you.
So, How to call a program using the CL CALL PGM and send data to and from?

**Option 1)** If you only need to input data, you can pass data in the string, you still can't get anything back.
You can bind a variable for the whole command:

```
$query = "CALL QCMDEXC(?)";
$result->bindParam(1, $cmd, PDO::PARAM_STR|PDO::PARAM_INPUT);
$cmd = "CALL PGM(IBMIPGM) PARM(INPARM)";
```

This will pass the text 'INPARM' to the program.
The next issue you will run into is parameter delimiting and escape characters.
The IBM parameters are space separated so you can pass two or more with spaces between:

```
$cmd = 'CALL PGM(IBMIPGM) PARM(INPARM1 INPARM2)';
```

If you have a space in your string, then it must be delimited by single quotes:

```
$cmd = "CALL PGM(IBMIPGM) PARM('INPARM1PART1 INPARM1PART2' INPARM2)";
```

Ok so far using php double quotes for the string . If we used php single quotes then we would have to escape them with backslash. To add complication, if you do not delimit the IBM parameters with single quotes, then strings will be converted to uppercase. If your string contains a single quote then it must be escaped. The IBM escape character in sql and CL is a single quote.
Here is an example of setting a data area:

```
$query = "CALL QCMDEXC(?)";
$result->bindParam(1, $cmd, PDO::PARAM_STR|PDO::PARAM_INPUT);
$val = "Don''t forget to escape single quotes";
$cmd = "CHGDTAARA DTAARA(MYLIB/TESTDTA *ALL) VALUE('$val')";
```

You must think about the nested strings and escaping, if you didn't use a bound variable, you'd have to double escape:

```
$cmd = "CALL QCMDEXC('CHGDTAARA DTAARA(MYLIB/TESTDTA *ALL) VALUE(''Don''''t forget to escape single quotes'')')";
```

Just for example, if you were to use php single quotes:

```
$cmd = 'CALL QCMDEXC(\'CHGDTAARA DTAARA(MYLIB/TESTDTA *ALL) VALUE(\'\'Don\'\'\'\'t forget to escape single quotes\'\')\')';
```

You should have a function to sanitise any data coming from users (or even yourself), to prevent injection attacks, as binding the variable is only binding the command string, they could inject into the command string, so sanitising and escaping is very important!

**Option 2)** Use PHP XMLSERVICE Toolkit.
You will be able to add input and output parameters, you can call programs directly with the PGMCall method, or run CL using the CLCommand method, which also returns data. I know it works with ibm_db2 and odbc connectors, not sure which connector you are using with PDO. It also has an experimental http transport type.

**Option 3)** Create an External Bound Procedure.
If your *PGM that you are calling is RPG, ILE, C, JAVA, etc (view link below) then you can probably create an external bound procedure for it.
Create it in sql:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE PGM_PROC ( IN INVALUE CHAR(10), OUT OUTVALUE CHAR(10), INOUT INOUTVAL CHAR(20) ) 
LANGUAGE C
EXTERNAL NAME IBMIPGM
PARAMETER STYLE GENERAL;
```

You can then bind php variables to it and call directly:

```
$query = "CALL PGM_PROC(?,?,?)";

$result->bindParam(1, $invalue, PDO::PARAM_STR|PDO::PARAM_INPUT, 10);
$result->bindParam(2, $outvalue, PDO::PARAM_STR|PDO::PARAM_OUTPUT, 10);
$result->bindParam(3, $inoutvalue, PDO::PARAM_STR|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, 20);
```

Resources:
Application services: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.5?topic=services-qcmdexc-procedure

XMLSERVICE Toolkit: http://www.youngiprofessionals.com/wiki/index.php/XMLSERVICE/XMLSERVICE
and https://github.com/IBM/xmlservice
and https://help.zend.com/zend/current/content/toolkit_service_class.htm

External Procedure: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.5?topic=statements-create-procedure-external

Excellent IBMi blog: https://www.rpgpgm.com/p/list-of-all-posts.html#3